# Detect collision of btCompoundShape with btSphereShape with Bullet and LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, collision-detection, bullet

I'm trying to detect collision between `btCompountShape` and `btSphereShape` with `Bullet` library used in `LibGDX` project.

My detection method looks like this:

```
def checkCollision(left: btCollisionObject, right: btCollisionObject) = {
  val leftWrapper = new CollisionObjectWrapper(left)
  val rightWrapper = new CollisionObjectWrapper(right)

  val algorithm = collisionDispatcher.findAlgorithm(leftWrapper.wrapper, rightWrapper.wrapper)

  val info = new btDispatcherInfo()
  val result = new btManifoldResult(leftWrapper.wrapper, rightWrapper.wrapper)

  algorithm.processCollision(leftWrapper.wrapper, rightWrapper.wrapper, info, result)

  val r = result.getPersistentManifold.getNumContacts > 0

  result.dispose()
  info.dispose()
  algorithm.dispose()
  leftWrapper.dispose()
  rightWrapper.dispose()

  r
}
```

It works perfectly fine when I use it to detect collision between two `btSphereShape` objects. But when I pass one that is `btCompoundShape` it fails. For testing I created my `btCompoundShape` with only one child shape, namely simple `btSphereShape`. It fails with following error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.game.CollisionDetector$class.checkCollision(CollisionDetector.scala:19)
  at com.game.SmlPwsat2Game.checkCollision(SmlPwsat2Game.scala:14)
  at com.game.SmlPwsat2Game.render(SmlPwsat2Game.scala:87)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:207)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

I checked that `result.getPersistentManifold` returns null. Why? And what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `btCompoundShape` is a compound of multiple shapes. There is no such thing as one algorithm for multiple shapes. You need an algorithm for each shape it is made of against the sphere.

That being said, you should never even have to care about that, because the collision world takes care of that for you. It looks like you stopped in the middle of my tutorial. The `checkCollision` method is only intended as example. To show you what's going on. Not to actually use it.

Check https://xoppa.github.io/blog/using-the-libgdx-3d-physics-bullet-wrapper-part1/, make sure to read the entire tutorial, *don't* stop in the middle. Later on in the tutorial I show you how to use a collision world and the `checkCollision` method is removed.

Comment: Ok, that's what I did - started playing with your tutorial and kind of drifted away from it. Thanks, I'll read on.